# React Redux action fires too many times after conditional is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

React functional component state:

```
const [image, setImage] = useState("");
const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("");
```

This is the useEffect in my component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.profile();
}, [props]);
```

You can upload a profile picture with this `input`.

```
<input
  style={{ display: "none" }}
  name="image"
  id="image"
  type="file"
  accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg"
  value={""}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setImage(e.target.files[0]);
  }}
/>
<label htmlFor="image">
  <img src={user.user.image} alt="profile pic" />
</label>
```

Update profile Redux action:

```
export const updateProfile = (updateProfile) => (dispatch) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
        axios
            .put("http://localhost:5000/updateProfile", updateProfile, {
                headers: { "X-Auth-Token": token },
            })
            .then((res) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: UPDATE_PROFILE,
                    payload: res.data,
                });
            });
    }
};
```

And this is in my React functional component:

```
if (image) {
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
        uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {},
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            () => {
                storage
                    .ref("images")
                    .child(image.name)
                    .getDownloadURL()
                    .then((url) => {
                        setImageUrl(url);
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        props.updateProfile({
                            image: imageUrl,
                        });
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        setImage("");
                        setImageUrl("");
                    });
            }
        );
}
```

So the image uploads successfully and changes the state and displays the new image, great. However, it fires the Redux action 4 times ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc4PC.png)). Why? It should only fire once.

I fire this function based on the user selecting an image from the file browser. Then the image state changes, conditional runs because there is an image, then it should run the firebase function and my redux action, in this order. Is it possible to fire it only once and in this order?

**EDIT:**

The conditional is just above the return() in this functional component.

This is my props.profile()

```
export const profile = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: FETCHING_PROFILE,
    });

    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
        axios
            .get("http://localhost:5000/profile", {
                headers: { "X-Auth-Token": token },
            })
            .then((res) =>
                dispatch({
                    type: PROFILE,
                    payload: res.data,
                })
            );
    }
};
```

Comment: What does `props.profile()` do?

Comment: Also, where is your  `if (image) {` condition in your react function component? Does it run on every render?

Comment: @RobertCooper I edited my question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. No need to use state here.

```
onChange={imageOnChange}
```

And then...

```
const imageOnChange = (e) => {
        const image = e.target.files[0];

        console.log(image);

        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
        uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {},
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            () => {
                storage
                    .ref("images")
                    .child(image.name)
                    .getDownloadURL()
                    .then((url) => {
                        const u = url;
                        props.updateProfile({
                            image: u,
                        });
                    });
            }
        );
    };
```